# PHP - tratamento de erros

Tags: php

Estou construindo um sistema de envio de imagens para meu site. Realizando testes, com arquivos grandes, me deparo com o seguinte `warning`:

> POST Content-Length of 9489104 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in

Por que o arquivo ultrapassou o tamanho limite da variável $_POST.

Minha pergunta é como eu posso tratar esse erro, com uma mensagem do tipo "arquivo muito grande", para o usuário, sem que esse erro apareça para ele?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode pegar pelo content lenght:

```
<?php

if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && empty($_POST) &&
     empty($_FILES) && $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] > 0 )
{      
  $displayMaxSize = ini_get('post_max_size');

  switch ( substr($displayMaxSize,-1) )
  {
    case 'G':
      $displayMaxSize = $displayMaxSize * 1024;
    case 'M':
      $displayMaxSize = $displayMaxSize * 1024;
    case 'K':
       $displayMaxSize = $displayMaxSize * 1024;
  }

  $error = 'Posted data is too large. '.
           $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'].
           ' bytes exceeds the maximum size of '.
           $displayMaxSize.' bytes.";
}

?>
```

Os cases servem tão somente para converter o Max size para bytes, o segredo está no IF.

Esta resposta e as demais explicações estão no [link](https://andrewcurioso.com/blog/archive/2010/detecting-file-size-overflow-in-php.html)